# find p-value using R with a ANOVA table

Tags: r, anova, p-value

[image: CLICK HERE FOR THE PHOTO OF ANOVA TABLE!]

I have the anova table like this and the question is asking me to find the p-value using R or otherwise, can someone help me with this? I'm totally struggling with this question.

Comment: have a look at `?pf`

Answer (score 5):

It should be as follows:

`1-pf(171.5410/13.3074, 2, 325)`

You get your F statistic from the ratio of `MS-Group` and `MS-Error`. Plugging in the degrees of freedom for numerator and denominator (i.e. 2 and 325 respectively) into F distribution, we get p-value as:

```
4.098518e-06
```

In other words, difference among means is statistically significant.

Comment: To get upper tail probabilities you should use `lower.tail=FALSE` with `pf` rather than doing `1-pf`; it's considerably more accurate in the upper tail